# Batch error in goto control-flow

Tags: batch-file

Since I'm a beginner in writing batch-files I wrote the following program:

```
::SET a=1
SET b=2
::SET c=3

IF EXIST %a% GOTO aa
IF EXIST %b% GOTO bb
IF EXIST %c% GOTO cc

:aa
ECHO aa
GOTO end

:bb
ECHO bb
GOTO end

:cc
ECHO cc
GOTO end

:end
ECHO end

pause > nul
```

I expected it to print out

```
SET b=2

IF EXIST GOTO aa    
IF EXIST 2 GOTO bb

ECHO bb
end
```

But instead it was

```
SET b=2

IF EXIST GOTO aa    
IF EXIST 2 GOTO bb   rem it recognized b=2.. 
IF EXIST GOTO cc

ECHO aa              rem ..but did not used the GOTO path!
end
```

What went wrong? How can I contol to enter `:bb` instead of `:aa`?

Comment: `IF EXIST` checks for the existence of a file. Do you have a file called `2` in the current directory? Is that what you wanted to check for?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever No, the check was meant to be if-the-value-was-defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `defined`The code:

```
@echo off

::SET a=1
SET b=2
::SET c=3

IF defined a GOTO aa
IF defined b GOTO bb
IF defined c GOTO cc

:aa
ECHO aa
GOTO end

:bb
ECHO bb
GOTO end

:cc
ECHO cc
GOTO end

:end
ECHO end

pause > nul
exit
```